# tp-link Archer T4U make error (kali linux)

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, make

I followed steps from TP-Link and get this error when I type:

```
$make 
.
.
.
make[3]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-5.7.0-kali1-common/scripts/Makefile.build:272: /home/arishat/file/T4Uv3_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_beta/os_dep/osdep_service.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-5.7.0-kali1-common/Makefile:1745: /home/arishat/file/T4Uv3_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_beta] Error 2
make[1]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-5.7.0-kali1-common/Makefile:180: sub-make] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.7.0-kali1-686-pae'
make: *** [Makefile:1998: modules] Error 2
```

I also tried to download `compat-wireless` from [OpenWRT](https://mirror2.openwrt.org/sources/) and I also got an error in `make` command.

Then I searched it on GitHub and downloaded https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au

Installation was complete but now I get a messeage when I open wifi:

```
device not ready
```

My TP-Link device is identified but it doesn't work at all.

I also tried restarting network manager and the system and even updating everything but still nothing.
..................
EDIT : adding ALL results
arishat@ef-sf:~/file/T4Uv3_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_beta$ make clean && make
#make -C /lib/modules/5.7.0-kali1-686-pae/build M=/home/arishat/file/T4Uv3_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_beta clean
cd hal ; rm -fr */*/*/*.mod.c */*/*/*.mod */*/*/*.o */*/*/.*.cmd */*/*/*.ko
cd hal ; rm -fr */*/*.mod.c */*/*.mod */*/*.o */*/.*.cmd */*/*.ko
cd hal ; rm -fr */*.mod.c */*.mod */*.o */.*.cmd */*.ko
cd hal ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd core ; rm -fr */*.mod.c */*.mod */*.o */.*.cmd */*.ko
cd core ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd os_dep/linux ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd os_dep ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd platform ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
rm -fr Module.symvers ; rm -fr Module.markers ; rm -fr modules.order
rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko *~
rm -fr .tmp_versions
make ARCH=i386 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/5.7.0-kali1-686-pae/build M=/home/arishat/file/T4Uv3_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_beta  modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.7.0-kali1-686-pae'
CC [M]  /home/arishat/file/T4Uv3_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_beta/core/rtw_cmd.o
In file included from /home/arishat/file/T4Uv3_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_beta/include/drv_types.h:30,
from /home/arishat/file/T4Uv3_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_beta/core/rtw_cmd.c:17:
/home/arishat/file/T4Uv3_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_beta/include/wifi.h:1031: warning: "IEEE80211_MAX_AMPDU_BUF" redefined
1031 | #define IEEE80211_MAX_AMPDU_BUF 0x40
| I COULDNT PUT HERE EVERYTHING BUT EVERYTHING SEEMS NORMAL BEFORE THIS :
|
In file included from /home/arishat/file/T4Uv3_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_beta/include/osdep_service_linux.h:83,
from /home/arishat/file/T4Uv3_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_beta/include/osdep_service.h:50,
from /home/arishat/file/T4Uv3_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_beta/include/drv_types.h:27,
from /home/arishat/file/T4Uv3_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_beta/os_dep/osdep_service.c:19:
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.7.0-kali1-common/include/linux/ieee80211.h:1460: note: this is the location of the previous definition
1460 | #define IEEE80211_MAX_AMPDU_BUF  0x100
|
/home/arishat/file/T4Uv3_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_beta/os_dep/osdep_service.c: In function ‘isFileReadable’:
/home/arishat/file/T4Uv3_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_beta/os_dep/osdep_service.c:2190:10: error: implicit declaration of function ‘get_ds’; did you mean ‘get_da’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
2190 |   set_fs(get_ds());
|          ^~~~~~
|          get_da
/home/arishat/file/T4Uv3_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_beta/os_dep/osdep_service.c:2190:10: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘set_fs’
2190 |   set_fs(get_ds());
|          ^~~~~~~~
|          |
|          int
In file included from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.7.0-kali1-common/include/linux/uaccess.h:11,
from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.7.0-kali1-common/include/linux/sched/task.h:11,
from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.7.0-kali1-common/include/linux/sched/signal.h:9,
from /home/arishat/file/T4Uv3_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_beta/include/osdep_service.h:47,
from /home/arishat/file/T4Uv3_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_beta/include/drv_types.h:27,
from /home/arishat/file/T4Uv3_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_beta/os_dep/osdep_service.c:19:
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.7.0-kali1-common/arch/x86/include/asm/uaccess.h:29:40: note: expected ‘mm_segment_t’ {aka ‘struct ’} but argument is of type ‘int’
29 | static inline void set_fs(mm_segment_t fs)
|                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
/home/arishat/file/T4Uv3_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_beta/os_dep/osdep_service.c: In function ‘retriveFromFile’:
/home/arishat/file/T4Uv3_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_beta/os_dep/osdep_service.c:2228:11: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘set_fs’
2228 |    set_fs(get_ds());
|           ^~~~~~~~
|           |
|           int
In file included from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.7.0-kali1-common/include/linux/uaccess.h:11,
from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.7.0-kali1-common/include/linux/sched/task.h:11,
from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.7.0-kali1-common/include/linux/sched/signal.h:9,
from /home/arishat/file/T4Uv3_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_beta/include/osdep_service.h:47,
from /home/arishat/file/T4Uv3_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_beta/include/drv_types.h:27,
from /home/arishat/file/T4Uv3_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_beta/os_dep/osdep_service.c:19:
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.7.0-kali1-common/arch/x86/include/asm/uaccess.h:29:40: note: expected ‘mm_segment_t’ {aka ‘struct ’} but argument is of type ‘int’
29 | static inline void set_fs(mm_segment_t fs)
|                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
/home/arishat/file/T4Uv3_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_beta/os_dep/osdep_service.c: In function ‘storeToFile’:
/home/arishat/file/T4Uv3_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_beta/os_dep/osdep_service.c:2263:11: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘set_fs’
2263 |    set_fs(get_ds());
|           ^~~~~~~~
|           |
|           int
In file included from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.7.0-kali1-common/include/linux/uaccess.h:11,
from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.7.0-kali1-common/include/linux/sched/task.h:11,
from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.7.0-kali1-common/include/linux/sched/signal.h:9,
from /home/arishat/file/T4Uv3_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_beta/include/osdep_service.h:47,
from /home/arishat/file/T4Uv3_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_beta/include/drv_types.h:27,
from /home/arishat/file/T4Uv3_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_beta/os_dep/osdep_service.c:19:
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.7.0-kali1-common/arch/x86/include/asm/uaccess.h:29:40: note: expected ‘mm_segment_t’ {aka ‘struct ’} but argument is of type ‘int’
29 | static inline void set_fs(mm_segment_t fs)
|                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[3]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-5.7.0-kali1-common/scripts/Makefile.build:272: /home/arishat/file/T4Uv3_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_beta/os_dep/osdep_service.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-5.7.0-kali1-common/Makefile:1745: /home/arishat/file/T4Uv3_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_beta] Error 2
make[1]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-5.7.0-kali1-common/Makefile:180: sub-make] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.7.0-kali1-686-pae'
make: *** [Makefile:1998: modules] Error 2

Comment: Make normally carries on with all possible parts of the dependency tree after an error, and throws error 1 or 2 to indicate there were previous errors. There should be more specific messages in the section of log that you didn't post.

Answer (score 0):

Make failed overall because it found four errors in the C code you downloaded.

/home/arishat/file/T4Uv3_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_beta/os_dep/osdep_service.c:2190:10: error: implicit declaration of function ‘get_ds’; did you mean ‘get_da’?

/home/arishat/file/T4Uv3_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_beta/os_dep/osdep_service.c:2190:10: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘set_fs’

/home/arishat/file/T4Uv3_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_beta/os_dep/osdep_service.c:2228:11: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘set_fs’

/home/arishat/file/T4Uv3_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_beta/os_dep/osdep_service.c:2263:11: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘set_fs’

All of those relate to the same piece of code: `set_fs(get_ds());`

It is quite possible this is just an incompatibility between compiler and source versions. There should be a README.txt (or release notes or similar) in the top level of the source you downloaded, and you can check what requirements (like compiler version) it needs. Or there may be some obvious issue you can trace back to.

You can register with a forum at community.tp-link.com/en and there is a technical support link on the front page.

Otherwise, I can only refer you to this post and the links it contains:

[Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me)

Comment: the readme.txt is just giving some creditentials....                        I followed instructions from a pdf tp-link uploade for this usb adapter STEP-BY-STEP and this happened...                               I have also checked on the community there are some simmilar issues but none is answering